# Clipboard manager that syncs to iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, software-recommendation, copy-paste

There are many clipboard managers for Mac, but I'm looking for one that immediately makes my clippings (text, at least) available on iOS. Is there such an app?

Answer (score 1):

### [CloudClip](http://www.thinkbitz.com/cloudclip/)

> - Automatically or manually sync to the cloud whenever you copy text to the clipboard, in any app.
> - Automatically syncs through iCloud.
>
> [image]

Answer (score 0):

Copied - Copy and Paste Everywhere
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/copied-copy-paste-everywhere/id1015767349?mt=8